# using phantomjs to get jscript output

Tags: javascript, json, phantomjs

I have an internal webpage that I want to pull a piece of data from at time intervals.

I used curl to scrape the page but discovered the data i want is in a jscript.  So now I am trying to automate the jscript so i can get the output to text file, i can then parse the text file to get the figure I want.

I am a low level programmer, my higher level programming skills aren't great and I am at the limits of my knowledge.

```
   <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://x-x--x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x.com/igraph/chart?GraphType=zoomer&SchemaName1=Service&DataSet1=Prod&Marketplace1=LTN4-ShippingRouterController&HostGroup1=ALL&Host1=ALL&ServiceName1=WarehouseControlService&MethodName1=SortationOrchestrator.divert&Client1=ALL&MetricClass1=NONE&Instance1=NONE&Metric1=RECIRC&Period1=OneMinute&Stat1=n&Label1=SortationOrchestrator.divert%20RECIRC&SchemaName2=Service&MethodName2=SortationOrchestrator.scan&Metric2=Time&Label2=SortationOrchestrator.scan%20Time&DecoratePoints=true&TZ=Europe%2FLondon@TZ%3A%20London&UpperValueLeft=150&LowerValueLeft=0&StartTime1=-PT2M&EndTime1=-PT1M&FunctionExpression1=M1%20%2F%20M2%20*%20100&FunctionLabel1=Recirc%20%25%20%5Bval%3A%20%7Bsum%7D%5D&FunctionYAxisPreference1=left&ChartLegend=true&WidthInPixels=400&HeightInPixels=400&Action=GetGraph&Version=2007-07-07&iGHrefresh=1475844553&Jsonp=MP.ChartController.loaded('chartdiv0'%2C"></script>
```

and I want the output of the Jsonp=MP.ChartController.loaded

which when you use firebug the output is

```
    MP.ChartController.loaded('chartdiv0',
     {
       error: '',
       width: 400,
       height: 400
      , summaryData: [

            { id: 0,
              label: 'Recirc % [val: 26.19]',
```

recirc val is what i'm after.

can i use phantomjs to run the jscript and output the json to txt file?

Comment: Are you sure you mean JScript and not just JavaScript? Those are two different things.

Comment: HI, yes these are the limits of my knowledge, I do mean Javascript.  Can you help?

Comment: @pyth0nBen can you please clarify your question more

Answer (score -1):

Not phantomjs but nodejs. PhantomJS is a headless browser and I dont think it would help much. Following code can demonstrate in better way: https://runkit.com/pankaj/periodic-ajax

Or if you wanna do it on a HTML page with jQuery then following code demonstrates that:

```js
var i = 0;
var intervalID = setInterval(function(){
    $.get( 'https://mocknode.herokuapp.com/id/', function (data) {
        console.log(i++, data)
    })
}, 5000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I really don't see how this answers the question.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Because the person is asking to get the page by phantomjs and then save its output in text file. I answered that it would be better to use nodejs. And the link in my answer clearly explains the periodic retrieval of data from ajax, further operations can be coded.

Comment: OP is asking about the retrieval of a specific part of information from the page. I don't see that in your answer.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I am targeting the last line of question very specifically. Though, I haven't added any code for saving json to file. Saving json to file can be done by opening a write stream to file.